# internet connection problem

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-express, visual-web-developer, internet-connection

I am using Visual Web Developer express and when I try to display the webpage I'm working on in a browser Internet Explorer cannot find the page. When I ask Internet Explorer to diagnose the problem I got the message ""localhost" is not set up to extablish a connection on port "52429" with this computer."
Any ideas what to do?

Comment: When I try opening by typing the file path directly in Intenet Explorer, I am told "Cannot use XML input using XSL style sheet". There is an ASP.net Development Server that is supposed to make sure I can open my pages in a browser but it doesn't seem to be working correctly. Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understand your question correctly.

Your web page is probably stored on the local hard disk, but you are trying to access it thru some sort of server running on your PC.

Web browser can actually load pages from the hard disk.  For example, if your page is in c:\test, you could just type "c:\test\index.html" into the address bar.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! When I tried opening the page by typing the file path directly in the browser I was told "Cannot view XML input using XSL style sheet."